# $\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n} + 1) \leq 2n$

Tags: inequality

Show that $ \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n} + 1) \leq 2n $ by any way possible, when $n\geq1$.

To show that this inequality is true I jotted down some inequalities that seemed similar to this like: $ \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+1) \geq \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}) = n $ and $ 2n \geq n $ but I can't find a way to somehow use them to show the given inequality.

Comment: $\sqrt{n} \leq n$ holds for any nonnegative integer $n$.

Comment: Forgot to mention that $ n \geq 1 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+1) = n + \sqrt{n} \leq 2n.$

Note by the last step that the inequality only holds when $n \geq 1$ or $n = 0.$

Answer (score 2):

The inequlaity is obvious for $n=0$. If $n$ is a positive integer we have $\sqrt n +1 \leq  \sqrt n +\sqrt n = 2\sqrt n$. Multiply both sides by $\sqrt n$.

Comment: Just a note: Inequality is true for $n=0$ as well but your idea will only work for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Aren't you assuming $n\gt 1$ ? Because your first inequality is false when $n=0.5$

Comment: @rsadhvika The OP's inequality is also false when $n = 0.5$.

Comment: @Bungo Ahh right. I see... Also the letter $n$ also hints to natural numbers. So it's good :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \ge 1$;

Then

$√n \ge 1$ ;

Multiply inequality by $√n$: $n \ge √n;$

Add $n$ to both sides :

$2n \ge √n +n= √n(1+√n).$

Answer (score 0):

We are given
$\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+1)\leq 2n,\,\,n\geq 1$
$\Rightarrow \sqrt{n} + 1\leq \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n}} = 2\sqrt{n}$
$\Rightarrow \sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n}\leq-1$
$\Rightarrow -\sqrt{n} \leq -1$
$\Rightarrow \sqrt{n}\geq 1$
Which is certainly true for all $n\geq 1.$